# Folder path of select file in AppleScript

Tags: applescript, filesplitting

I'm creating simple script to convert mp3 files using shell script. I decided to automate my conversion using applescript.
Basically what I'm doing is selecting mp3 file then splitting that file using my command line and i want to create a folder where the file is located (script will create that for me).

Now I just need to figure out how to get a path to a folder of the file.
How do I do that in applescript?

Here is the script that I have so far:

```
set mp3FileToSplit to choose file without invisibles
set thepath to mp3FileToSplit as text
set theposix to POSIX path of thepath

tell application "Finder" to set file_name to (name of mp3FileToSplit)

do shell script "/opt/local/bin/mp3splt -t 3.00 -d  " & quoted form of file_name & " " & quoted form of theposix
```

Right now what that script does is creating folder on the root of my hard drive and I need to be in the folder where the file is located.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tell application "Finder"
    set f to POSIX file "/private/etc/" as alias
    POSIX path of ((folder of f) as alias) -- /private/
end tell
```

Or

```
do shell script "dirname /private/etc/" -- /private
```